# Django channels page stuck on loading

Tags: python, django, redis, django-channels

I created a simple Django Channels consumer that connects  to a Redis channel and receives some data from this channel, i want to send this data to the frontend.

The consumer is able to connect to the consumer and receives the data; the problem is that if i try to load the page when the consumer is running, the page will be stuck on loading. I'm sure this happens because the connection to the Redis channel is a blocking operation, or it could be a problem with threads. I'm new to this concepts, so i decided to make a question for it.

Here is my consumer:

```
class EchoConsumer(AsyncConsumer):

    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        self.send({
                'type': 'websocket.accept'
            })

        self.receive(event)

    def receive(self, event):
        redis_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
        connection = redis.StrictRedis.from_url(redis_url, decode_responses=True)
        channel = 'TEST'
        params = urllib.parse.parse_qs(self.scope.get('query_string', b'').decode('utf-8'))

        pubsub = connection.pubsub(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
        pubsub.subscribe(channel)

        for message in pubsub.listen():

            # self.send({
            #   'type': 'websocket.send',
            #   'text': message['data'],
            # })

            print(message['data'])


    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        print('DISCONNECTED!')
```

So what happens is that i can see the data being printed to my console, but if i try to leave that page and reach a different part of my site, the page will get stuck on loading. Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things you could be trying to do here.

## Subscribing once and sending this information to all open connections

the issue you are having is `pubsub.listen():` will loop forever (never stopping). So your consumer will never continue and be able to process any more messages.

Since (at least in this example) it looks like you are always hitting redis with static values (not dependent on the request from the user) you are better off doing this subscription outside of your consumer. (in a django command https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Then you can have that command then send these messages over a channel layer to your subscribed consumers.

this would make your consumer look like this

```py
class EchoConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    async def on_message(self, message):
        await self.send_json(message)
```

then in your management command instread of printing you can send the message using

```py
async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        "echo_group",
        {"type": "on.message", "rate":Rate, "quantity": Quantity, "symbol": Symbol, "order": Order},
    )
```

---

## Subscribing once for each open connection

This you should only do if you expect the subscription to be different for each websocket connection. (eg you are using a value in the url/query/headers or subscribing only when the user sends a ws message to your consumer with a given filter value).

Doing this is a `LOT` more complex for a few reasons:

1. Redis will not handle as many open connections to it as you can have websocket connections.
2. You need to setup a nested async task that can handle the events from redis in such a way that they do not block the rest of the consumer.

If you do still need this functionality i'm happy to update the answer with a solution (but warning it will be long).

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer, it's exactly like you said, the loop can't be in the Consumer, i made some research and the creator of Channels said the same. Here is the thing: I won't have a single channel, in fact there are around 600 channels (one for each market) , this is why I wanted to connect from the consumer, because it would connect straight to the interested channels, get data only from that channel and the other channels are not active. In this case I would have around 10 connections (i don't expect to have a lot of users)

Comment: The big problem about using the Django management command is that, in order to broadcast the data, it needs to connect to all the channels, so it would be 600+ connection, here is the problem. I was thinking how doing this: find a way to get the active groups (for active i means when the use opens the page), get the names of the active groups (the markets) and connect to those redis channels

Comment: Redds does support subscribing to multiple channels on a single connection. You will need to use one of the async Redis libs (such as the one used by djangos redis layer: https://github.com/django/channels_redis). You could then create a group name for each set of data and the consumers can `group_add` by sending a json message to them requesting a subscription to that set of data.

Comment: I will try to write up a short example (add to that above answer) on how you might instread do this within a consumer (using a nested async task) but i would suggest against it in most case.

Comment: I know it's not a good way to go, but what option would i have in this case? Use a whole different approach which doesn't involve Redis?

Comment: My problem is that, basically: i have a data collector script running on X server which is streaming some trades for X number of market. I need a way to, when the user opens the page, make the user have the trades that the data collector is streaming. I chose to use Redis because the PUB/SUB system seemed perfect for this: the data collector creates a channel for every market, when the user needs the trades for XYZ markets, they will be connected to the XYZ Redis channel where data collector is streaming the trades for that market.

Comment: I would be happy to know there are other ways to do this, other approaches i considered were Pusher, but it will end up being too expensive for me. Keep in mind that i don't have to store anything, the trades are only meant to be shown to the use whenever the page is opened, that's it; i'm probably making it too more diffiicult than it actually is

Comment: i would suggest create a async websocket consumer that gets these trades and writes them to a group you can have many groups.

From your Server that has these trades it can open a ws connection ans send them to this consumer.

then when users connect (to a different consumer) they send a ws message saying what groups they are interested in, that then subscribes that consume instance to those groups. 

you can then use the django channels redis layer to handle this, under the hood it is using the same pubsub you wanted to use but you dont need to manage it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211344/discussion-between-jack022-and-matthaus-woolard).